# Ruby on Rails 5 - stable version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm going to work on a new project and I would like to know the best rails version to use. I see on the main site the "Latest version — Rails 5.0.0.1 released August 11, 2016", but as long as I knew, Rails 5 was in beta phase. Is that version stable to use? Thanks

Comment: This question will become out of date extremely fast.

Comment: and your comment as well..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this new version 5.0.0.1 is stable, I have created an application using actioncable, activejobs and other added things, and  I think its best version you can use.

Comment: But make sure that you have Ruby 2.2.2 or newer to work with Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Current stable version is Rails 5.1.6 as of today